# how to select multiple columns in subquery(hql)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, subquery, hql

Is there a way to select multiple columns in a subquery of hql?

I want to convert the following mysql query to hql

```
select u.name, sub.cnt from user u
  inner join (select user_id, count(user_id) cnt from user_log group by user_id order by cnt desc limit 5) sub 
    on u.id = sub.user_id;
```

But in hql, I know that can use subquery only in where clause

Comment: You can use createSqlQuery to process your query al SQL or you can map in right mode objects User and UserLog to get the correct query. P.S. in your SQL query you have omitted the GROUP BY on USER_ID field

Comment: oh i miss group by.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a pure Hibernate solution. I talk about that in my Blog post.

But there is a FluentJPA solution that you may consider:

```java
FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL((User u) -> {

    UserIdCount sub = subQuery((UserLog log) -> {
        int count = alias(COUNT(log.getUserId()), UserIdCount::getCount);
        SELECT(log.getUserId(), count);
        FROM(log);
        ORDER(BY(count).DESC());
        LIMIT(5);
    });

    SELECT(u.getName(), sub.getCount());
    FROM(u).JOIN(sub).ON(u.getId() == sub.getUserId());
});

return query.createQuery(em, UserNameCount.class).getSingleResult();
```

which produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT t0.name, q0.count 
FROM USER t0  INNER JOIN (SELECT t1.user_id, COUNT(t1.user_id) AS count 
FROM USER_LOG t1 
ORDER BY  COUNT(t1.user_id)  DESC   
LIMIT 5 ) q0  ON (t0.id = q0.user_id)
```

Entities I used (declared with lombok):

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Table(name = "USER")
class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Table(name = "USER_LOG")
class UserLog {
    private Long userId;
}

@Tuple
@Getter
class UserIdCount {
    private Long userId;
    private int count;
}

@Tuple
@Data
class UserNameCount {
    private int count;
    private String name;
}
```